# Setting text color in ComboBoxItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors, combobox

I want to set the text color for *`PASS`* as `GREEN` and the text color for *`FAIL`* as `RED`. I can't seem to find the solution. I need to do this in pure XAML.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="LocatedCorrectly" Width="100" 
          Height="25" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">

    <ComboBoxItem Content="PASS" Tag="PASS" IsSelected="True"/>                
    <ComboBoxItem Content="FAIL" Tag="FAILED"  />
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Use Triggers for the same (you should inherit the base style too)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="Content" Value="PASS">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
       </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers> 
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest altering your style by creating style document separately in Window.Resources, and then styling your ComboBox items to have whatever foreground color you want.

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

If you want to keep it in Application.Resources, then I think you need to track down what x:Static brush key is used for setting the TextBlock.Text color and overwrite that in your ComboBox.Resources